# Change the text of links with an specific class, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace, hyperlink

I am looking for a way to replace the text of all the links with an specific class, using javascript (not jquery). I would like all the links with that specific class, to have a generic text such as: "click here".

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Suggest to start by reading about HTML DOM 'document.get*' functions: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp and then proceed to read about DOM element functions: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp. You would like to get all DOM elements for the specific tag, iterate through the array var and manipulate only the elements with the class you are concerned with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `getElementsByClassName` to acquire an array of the links. You can then loop through these elements making any changes required.

Heres [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/snq4bxvk/) that also includes some validation to only chenge the text of anchor tags in case you use targetClass for anything else in other elements.

EDIT: looks like other beat me to it :-) (also fixing type in function)

Comment: It works perfect Sam but, I made a dumb mistake when I asked. I meant all the links within an specific class. Not with, within. The links are going to be inside a div with an specific class.

Comment: No problem, just use the original code to get the divs with the class then `getElementsByTagName` to find the `a` tags within those `div`s.
I've updated [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/snq4bxvk/1/) with a new example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".yourclass");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; links++)
{
    links[i].innerHTML = "click here";
}
```

Comment: It works perfect Nekomajin but, I made a dumb mistake when I asked. I meant all the links within an specific class. Not with, within. The links are going to be inside a div with an specific class

Comment: Change the parameter of the querySelector to `".yourclass a"`!

Comment: It works, but, only for the first div with the link. Ther are anothe 9 links in the page with same class. ):

Comment: OK, so you have multiple divs with the same class, and each div contains multiple links?

Comment: Actually, multiple divs with the same class, and each div contains only one link.

Comment: That's no difference. Did you use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Are the links direct children of the divs, or there is any element inside the div which contains the links?

Comment: Well, it should work. But never mind! You have the solution now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It's using ES6, so make sure you're using either Chrome Canary or a [transpiler like Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Say this is your markup...

```
<a class="classname" href="#">STUBBED</a>
<a class="classname" href="#">MOCKED</a>
<a class="classname" href="#">PLACEHOLDER</a>
```

This as your JS should work...

```
let refs = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
refs = [].slice.apply(refs);

refs.forEach(ref => ref.innerHTML = 'click here');
```

Comment: It works perfect Wcarroll but, I made a dumb mistake when I asked. I meant all the links within an specific class. Not with, within. The links are going to be inside a div with an specific class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var c = document.querySelectorAll(".example>a"); 
    for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        c[i].innerHTML = "Click Me!";           
    } 
}
```

This should do the trick in pure javascript